# POST запрос на авторизацию

Tags: php, curl

Доброго времени суток, имеется на данный момент такой php код для авторизации:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
setlocale(LC_TIME, "ru_RU.utf8");

$login_params = explode('=', file_get_contents('php://input'));
auth();

function auth() {
    $auth_curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($auth_curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://uapi.ucoz.com/index/sub/',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Host: uapi.ucoz.com'
        ),
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
            'user' => $login_params[0],
            'password' => $login_params[1],
            'a' => '2',
            'ajax' => '2',
            'api_request' => '1',
            'api_login_rnd' => get_rand_str(),
            'api_login_crc' => get_rand_str(),
            '_tp_' => 'xml'
        ))
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($auth_curl);
    curl_close($auth_curl);
    echo $response;
}

function get_rand_str() {
    $length = rand(8, 10) - 1;
    $num = rand(0,9);
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $num .= rand(0, 9);
    }
    return $num;
}

?>
```

На вход ожидается связка `логин;пароль`, но сервер всегда отвечает, что логин или пароль не правильный. Если вписать вместо `$login_params[0]` конкретное значение логина, а вместо `$login_params[1]` конкретное значение пароля, при том те же, что отправляются через `file_get_contents('php://input')`, то авторизация проходит успешно. В итоге значения те же, но если использовать элементы массива, вместо конкретных вшитых значений, то авторизация не пройдет успешно. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том что в функции `auth` значение `login_params` недоступно.

Comment: @u_mulder, global'а не хватает?

Comment: @PhoEn-X: зачем global? передавайте этот массив как параметр функции auth: 
`function auth($params) {....}

auth($login_params); `

Comment: @Борис, вариант, конечно, но у меня по мере написания появилась тонна переменных, вложенность достигает 5 функций, в каждую передавать кучу параметров, конечно, не вариант, спас global. Не ожидал, что область видимости в php отличается от тех же плюсов или java. Но за ответ спасибо!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ из комментария:

Проблема в том что в функции `auth` значение `login_params` недоступно. В можете передать этот массив через аргумент функции:

```
$login_params = explode('=', file_get_contents('php://input'));
auth($login_params);

function auth($login_params) {
    // ...
}
```

А еще вы можете объявить переменную `$login_params` глобальной:

```
$login_params = explode('=', file_get_contents('php://input'));
auth();

function auth() {
    global $login_params;
    // ...
}
```

Стоит отметить, что использование глобальных переменных **существенно усложнит** поддержку кода в будущем.

Comment: Усложнит? Каким образом, если не секрет?

Comment: @PhoEn-X, большой проект в котором активно используются глобальные переменные сложно _отлаживать_. Сложность заключается в отслеживании всех тех мест в которых происходит обращение к таким переменным и логике их изменения. А самое страшное, что часто сложно понять в каком _порядке_ идут обращения к глобальной переменной и какой именно кусок кода записывает некорректную информацию в переменную. Я бы рекомендовал вообще отказаться от глобальных переменных в любых проекта крупнее 500 (условно) строк кода.

Comment: не наблюдал такого в программах на C++, Java. Если втыкать global во всех функциях, то можно имитировать такую же область видимости переменных, как и в вышеуказанных языках, а там коды у меня достигают 1к строк, ни разу проблемы не замечал)